# Looback: configure acl and relations to list all objects belonging to logged used

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreign-keys, acl, loopback

I'm trying to setup a loopback project and I'm running into a basic issue that I can't figure out.

So I've got basically a custom user model defined with the following relations and acls:

```
"relations": {
   ...
    "projects": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "project",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
}
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
]
```

And a 'project' model defined with properties:

```
"relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
},
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
]
```

First of all, to my surprise, when submitting a POST /projects while logged in, I was expecting the foreign key to be automagically put in the object but it looks like this has to be done manually. I suppose this is normal, I guess I was expecting too much from the framework.

That being said, I have been struggling to be able to list all the projects owned by the logged user. Performing a GET /projects/{id} with {id} being an object belonging to the logged user works. And when {id} points to an object NOT owned by the logged in user, I get, as expected, a 401.

But then, I was expecting that running /projects would return all the projects owned by the logged user but instead throws a 401 to my face.

What am I missing? Is my ACL setup wrong? Am I using the wrong method? I tried putting a filter like '{"where":{"userId":"myId"}}' but had no luck. I also tried the other endpoint /user/myId/projects with no better luck.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check your `model-config.json` to make sure, that the built-in `User` model isn't public? It's possible that you are routing to it instead of your custom `user` model.

Comment: @Ivan Schwarz Thanks for your reply, User isn't defined as public. Here is its def "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "realmRequired": true,
      "realmDelimiter": ":"
    }
  }

Comment: 1) According to [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html) the check for `$owner` is performed only for a remote method that has `:id` on the path, for example, `GET /projects/:id`. 2) `GET /user/:id/projects` returns 401, because it follows ACLs on your `user` model and these don't allow listing projects. You are looking to allow `__get__projects` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I was just getting loopback wrong, GET /projects was not the correct call but instead GET /users/{userId}/projects. ACL and relations seem to be correctly set.